# all possible combinations from different set of data (column) with different number of item in each column. combine left to right, no going back

Tags: combinations

I have this table in excel written in 8 different columns from A-H, not yet allowed to paste picture, please bear with my representation here

A1-A3   Single,Four, Dual 
B1-B4   Rte, Analyze, RA, None 
C1-C4   Balancing, LA, BLA, None 
D1-D4   Trans, ODS, Both, None 
E1-E10  English, Spanish, French, German, Turkish, Swedish, FinnISH, Chinese, Russian, Portuguese 
F1-F2   Rated, None 
G1-G2   Wifi, None 
H1-H2   External, Hard-sided

I want to get all possible combination from left to right. (so top to bottom in my diagram)
First combination would naturally be Single, Rte, Balancing, Trans, English, Rated, Wifi, External. The last one would be Four, None, None, None, Portuguese, None, None, Hardsided

Is there a way i could do that. I  love the idea of cartesian product but we dont have that. Plus, the number of column sometimes change and so are the number of entries in each set. I need it to be flexible.

I will appreciate so much if this will be solved.

Thanks and more power to all.